# How to sharing QRCode in react native using Expo?

Tags: react-native, share, expo, qr-code

I've been trying to share a QRCode image via Share component in expo. I am unsure how I would feed a QRCode image in the share function. Below is what I am attempting to run:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Share, Button} from 'react-native';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-image';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class ShareExample extends Component {
  onShare = async () => {
    try {
    const uri = <QRCode value={'here is my code'}/>
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:'sharing',
        uri: uri
      });

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <Button onPress={this.onShare} title="Share" />;
  }
}
```

I end up with a `Exception in HostFunction . . .` alert. I should be able to pass an image qr code with expo's share function correct?

Comment: Here using this ref you can generate Qr code
https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-qrcode-image

And then share it using share API of expo

Comment: That is the library I am using. I use the QR code component. I'm not sure how to pass it to share as an image

Answer (score 0):

First install [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) . For installing it you need to eject from expo ,coz expo doesnt allow linking and such complicated functionalities its always recommended to use bare react native coz expo has limitations.

Then try this pseudo code :

```
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-image';
import Share from 'react-native-share';



 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.qrCode = '';
  }

  openShareScreen() {
    if (this.qrCode) {
      const shareOptions = {
        type: 'image/jpg',
        title: '',
        url: this.qrCode
      };
      Share.open(shareOptions)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { type, address } = this.state;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openShareScreen}>
        <View>
          <QRCode
            getBase64={base64 => {
              this.qrCode = base64;
            }}
            value={address}
            size={150}
            bgColor="#FFFFFF"
            fgColor="#000000"
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

It's a great answer by kishan, hope it helps. feel free for doubts